# NuGet - Create nuspec with dependencies of packages.config

Tags: nuget

You can create a `.nuspec` file from a `.csproj` using simply `nuget.exe spec` from within the project folder.

However, the NuGet packages used by the project are not added to the `<dependencies>` section in the resulting `.nuspec` file.

Is there some way to make this happen automatically, seems like an obvious need?

At the moment I just copy paste a chunk from the `packages.config` file and tweak it a bit.

Comment: How does this not have an answer years later...

Comment: @CrescentFresh Still an issue. I'am encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `nuget pack` command with `-IncludeReferencedProjects` parameter. Then referenced projects will be included in **target** .nuspec file.

You could check that by renaming generated `.nupkg` to `.zip`, open it and analyze inner `.nuspec` file where dependencies will be listed.

Read here: [Nuget create a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#additional-options)

There's another case that you doing - it's to add the dependecy manually - this way you could set `version` attribute on referenced project. You could set it to minimum version, maximum version, etc...

Read here: [Nuspec file reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element)

Comment: I've not tried your suggestion. Is this for referenced projects only, or referenced NuGet packages, or both?

Comment: Referenced project should be added automatically by Nuget (best effort) to package. Referenced packages will be added to target nuspec file as dependencies (but has a fixed version)

Comment: Cool. Since I can't verify it, in the interests of accuracy, I'll wait for votes to drop in and accept your answer if others vote it up.